# Filtering Laravel datetime field for values after a certain time

Tags: php, laravel, datetime

I have an eloquent model that has a "start_time" field, which is of type dateTime, and I want users to be able to filter instances of the model based on time of day. So for example, the "start_time" field is in the format "2021-02-17 21:52:12" and I want the user to be able to send "08:00:00", and then filter all instances of the model so that only instances where the time portion of *start_time* is beyond 08:00:00. So "2021-01-10 07:59:59" would not appear while "2020-12-12 08:01:00" would appear.

I'm trying to do something like this, but it should only consider the time element:

```
if ($request->has('start_time')) {
    $return_shifts->where('start_time', '>', $request->start_time);
}
```

How would I correctly apply this filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`whereTime` method of laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses).

```
$return_shifts->whereTime('start_time', '>', $request->start_time);
```